# Why was Dawson not called to testify?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-few-good-men

Why was Dawson not called to testify that he was ordered to operate Code Red?

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a _Code Red_, **officially**!

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher- But Downey was called for the same reason! He testified that he was ordered to perform code red, but not by Jessup but by Dawson. So I worried why Dawson was not called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dawson was not called to testify as a legal maneuver. Criminal defense lawyers know when to withhold a testimony by the accused, because that would open up the prosecution's questions of his character. Dawson had the illegal fence-line shooting in his recent history where he shot at his counterpart. This was the same shooting Santiago reported, and was using to bargain his release from detail at Guantanamo.